# How can I write complex sql query in Laravel Elequent Query Builder

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5.3

Below shown is my query in SQL Server. It is working fine in SQL server studio. How can I write this in Laravel eloquent format?

I tried both DB::table('Price')... method and Price::where()... Model method. By using both methods I was not able to find the average.

Is this a limitation of the eloquent Query builder?
What is the best way to get output for this in Laravel?

```
select  month([Date]) as Date, 
avg(Oil) as Oil,
avg(Gas) as Gas,
 from [mydatabase].[dbo].[Price] 
 where year([Date]) = 2017
group by (month([Date]))
```

[This is the output I get from sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfk2r.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive this using [Raw expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions)

```
  $query = DB::table('Price')
                         ->select(DB::raw('avg(Oil) as Oil, avg(Gas) as Gas, month'))
                         ->where('year', '==', '2017')
                         ->groupBy('month')
                         ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
$result = DB::select(DB::raw("select  month([Date]) as Date, 
avg(Oil) as Oil,
avg(Oil_Parity) as Gas,
 from [mydatabase].[dbo].[Price] 
 where year([Date]) = :year
group by (month([Date]))"),['year'=>$year]);

dd($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use laravel's built in function **DB::raw("complex query goes here")**.

For your query something like below can be possible

```
$data = DB::raw("select  month([Date]) as Date, 
avg(Oil) as Oil,
avg(Gas) as Gas,
 from [mydatabase].[dbo].[Price] 
 where year([Date]) = ?
group by (month([Date]))", ['2017']);
```

[For DB::raw() More Check Here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#advanced-wheres)